# C# como crear un atributo para roles?

Tags: c#, .net

estoy trabajando en una aplicación (windows forms) esta trabaja con una conexion de base de datos sql server y tiene una tabla de usuarios que tienen roles.

La aplicación posee modulos o funcionalidades que son accesibles segun el rol del usuario:

```
[inventario; factura; ventas; reporte; administración]
```

la forma de restringir el acceso a los modulos podria ser:

1. mediante una validación con un condicional y verificar que el usuario que ha iniciado sesion es x entonces  poner la propiedad de x los controles enable=false.
2. igual que 1 pero ocultando los controles con la propiedad visible=false
3. igual de 1 pero realizando la validación en cada evento del control.

Ejemplo:

Metodo 1 y 2:

```
 private void MenuForm_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   //realizar la consulta a la base de datos y comprobar el rol
   if(rol == "bodega")
   {
     Ventas.enable = false;//Ventas.visible = false;
     Factura.enable = false;//Factura.visible = false;
   }
  }
```

metodo 3:

```
private void IngresoVentasButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(rol=="vendedor")
  {
   VentasForm ventas = new 
   VentasForm();
   ventas.Show();
  }
  else
  {
   MessageBox.Show("ud no tiene acceso a este modulo!");
  }
}
```

Para estos casos quisiera poder implementar attributos en las clases ,métodos o variables que permitiria restringir la ejecución del metodo(tarea) o poner las propiedades enable a false.

```
  [AutorizacionAttribute(rol="admin")]
```

Comment: No se si entiendo bien la pregunta. Quieres crear un atributo personalizado para luego poder consultarlo y ocultar o mostrar controles dependiendo de el?

Comment: lo que quiero es tener un atributo que bloquee el acceso a los controles ya sea poniendo enable a false o visible a false o en ese caso que impida ejecutar el metodo

Comment: Me parece que es demasiado amplia la pregunta. Te voy a dejar dos enlaces que explican todo lo que hay que hacer para crear atributos personalizados: [en codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827091/Csharp-Attributes-in-minutes) y en [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes)

Comment: Se me ocurre algo como declarar una List<string> con los roles permitidos (dentro de la clase Ventas; por ejemplo); y después una función que retorne true o false para determinar el acceso, a esa función la podes llamar desde, por ejemplo, el constructor de ventas, y en caso de no tener permiso, cerras la ventana y mandas un mbox

Comment: basicamente sería tratar de poder realizar estos comportamientos  httpsocial.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/9080224c-b887-442e-8afb-0e71e556b618/como-definir-roles-a-nivel-de-funciones?forum=vcses. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/d9f62202-dcb6-446c-81a9-708eca735724/desactivar-vistas-dependiendo-el-rol?forum=aspnetmvces. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181888/authorize-attribute-with-multiple-roles

Comment: aqui he encontrado otra cosa de lo que hablo. http://www.forosdelweb.com/f29/seguridad-basada-roles-aplicaciones-windos-forms-conectadas-bases-datos-701778/

Comment: Todos los ejemplos que pones se refieren a programacion web, que tiene algunas opciones preprogramadas de autenticacion y gestion de acceso. En WinForms, todo debes hacerlo tu.

Comment: [Aqui](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/windows-forms/controls-based-security-in-a-windows-forms-application/) tienes un articulo completisimo sobre como implementar un sistema de roles. En inglés,lamentablemente

Comment: se ingles tranquilo

Comment: gracias trabajare en ello para poder hacerlo mediante atributos.

Comment: No creo que sea excesivamente complicado. Echa un vistazo a los enlaces que te pasé en mi primer comentario para crear un atributo personalizado que puedas comprobar posteriormente en el código. Te animo a que si lo consigues lo compartas aqui respondiendo tu propia pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede utilizar el método interceptor con PostSharp, por ejemplo, en la llamada a este método de uso un Interceptor, en mi ejemplo de uso para hacer Caché. En el repositorio https://github.com/thiagoloureiro/TestaCache tiene el código completo.

```
[Serializable]
public class CacheableResultAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    private double _cacheRetainSeconds;

    public CacheableResultAttribute(params double[] cacheRetainSeconds)
    {
        _cacheRetainSeconds = cacheRetainSeconds[0];
    }

    public sealed override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        var cache = MethodResultCache.GetCache(args.Method);
        var arguments = args.Arguments.Union(new[] { WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name }).ToList();
        var result = cache.GetCachedResult(arguments);
        if (result != null)
        {
            args.ReturnValue = result;
            return;
        }

        base.OnInvoke(args);

        cache.CacheCallResult(args.ReturnValue, arguments, _cacheRetainSeconds);
    }
}

[CacheableResult(600)] 
public List<dynamic> ReturnCustomer()
{
    // return something
}
```

Comment: Aquí está un ejemplo para autorización: https://samples.postsharp.net/f/PostSharp.Samples.Authorization/

Comment: Para caché se puede usar https://doc.postsharp.net/caching.